# If field on first line equals a 'P' and field on the second line equals a 'W' then join the lines using awk

Tags: awk

Below is a fragment of a file I have:

```
Broad Street,Broad Street,P
Queen Street,Queen Street,P
Shoe Lane,Shoe Lane,P
Dev Way,Dev Way,P
Dev Way,Dev Way,W
Cameron Street,Cameron Street,P
Cameron Street,Cameron Street,W
```

I want to work down the file line by line and if field 3 on the first line is a 'P' and field 3 on the second line is a 'W' I want to keep both lines and join them together. However if the third field on the first line equals a 'P and the line below it also is a P I want to drop that line and move on to the next. So my results would be:

```
Dev Way,Dev Way,P,Dev Way,Dev Way,W
Cameron Street,Cameron Street,P,Cameron Street,Cameron Street,W
```

Is this possible to do in AWK?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";prevkey=""};{if ($NF=="W" && prevkey=="P") {print prev, $0}; prevkey=$NF; prev=$0}' datafile
```

Comment: Thank you, please could you explain how this works for me so I can understand it more? Thanks again :-) @erik bryer

Comment: To restate: If the last field on the current line is a W and the previous line's last field was a P, print out the previous line adjoined to the current line by a comma.
'BEGIN{FS=OFS="," ; prevkey=""} {  if ($NF=="W" && prevkey=="P") { print prev, $0 } prevkey=$NF prev=$0 }'
The BEGIN{} block runs first and once to initialize prevkey and set field separators to a comma. The rest of the prog. checks the last field on the current line ($NF) for a W. If it is a W, and the prev. line's last field (prevkey) was a P, print the prev. line (prev) then the current line ($0).